# Fill 2d array (matrix) based on rotation

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, rotation

I have a 2d matrix
I have to fill it diagonally, like a fluid.

Arbitrary rotation between -45 and 45 degrees. (for e.g. 32 degrees)

Some cases:

0 degree

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

-45 degree

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

45 degree

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: nice question, do you have some code to show?

Comment: @Nina my array myArray = [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1]];  var degree = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite perfect with the posted examples, but it's pretty close.  I made the array a bit bigger to get better resolution of the slants.  Just play with the `size` and `deg` variables to get desired output.

```
var arr = [];
var size = 10;
var deg = -45;

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){
    arr.push([]);
    for(var j = 0; j < size; j++){
        arr[i].push(0);
    }
}

var leftFill = .5 - (deg / 90);
var rightFill = .5 + (deg / 90);
var distanceToCover = rightFill - leftFill;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        var xHeight = (leftFill + ((j / (arr[i].length - 1)) * distanceToCover));
        var xPos = (arr.length - i) / size;
        if(xPos <= xHeight) arr[i][j] = 1; 
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var logStr = i + ': ';
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        logStr += (arr[i][j] + ' ');
    }
    console.log(logStr);    
}
```

Comment: Awesome!
Exactly what I wanted. It also works with a rectangle!

Comment: Sweet, glad this worked for you.  Just curious, what prompted the question?

Comment: This is for an ascii game. Nice trick for leftFill and rightFill.

I struggle to understand how you got xHeight.
But it does not matter. Whatever Works :P

Comment: Nice! xHeight basically figures out which column we are in and multiplies that by distanceToCover.  So 50% of the way through the columns we need to have added 50% of the distance to cover to our starting point.

  If this works for you, could you accept? Good luck with your game!